# Removing duplicate rows from CSV file using a awk/python

Tags: python, csv, awk, text-processing

I have a **file1.csv** with rows like:

```
adx,999-99-7708
ada,999-99-8101
ad1,999-99-8342
zda,103-54-7013
ad1,999-99-8591
```

**file2.csv** with rows like:

```
1967-05-08,583-50-3833,Trac,Mich,Ewell,3000,Cumming,3830 Man Rid Driv,tracey@gmail.com,(111) 123-4567,0123,GA,339061
1988-03-27,103-54-7013,Mar,Grac,Vea,30004,Au,2549 Walt Wa Apt D1,m@augu.edu,(706) 916-4817,021341,GA,339060
1973-11-16,183-54-5013,Carl,,Thom,30093,Norcross,1021 Ri Rid Drive,,,,,339059
```

wanted output:

```
1967-05-08,583-50-3833,Trac,Mich,Ewell,3000,Cumming,3830 Man Rid Driv,tracey@gmail.com,(111) 123-4567,0123,GA,339061
1973-11-16,183-54-5013,Carl,,Thom,30093,Norcross,1021 Ri Rid Drive,,,,,339059
```

I've tried

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$2]++; next} !a[$2]{print}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

which checking file2.txt duplicates from file1.txt and removing them, but still geting output

```
1967-05-08,583-50-3833,Trac,Mich,Ewell,3000,Cumming,3830 Man Rid Driv,tracey@gmail.com,(111) 123-4567,0123,GA,339061
1988-03-27,103-54-7013,Mar,Grac,Vea,30004,Au,2549 Walt Wa Apt D1,m@augu.edu,(706) 916-4817,021341,GA,339060
1973-11-16,183-54-5013,Carl,,Thom,30093,Norcross,1021 Ri Rid Drive,,,,,339059
```

when line #2 with **103-54-7013** should be removed. What i'm doing wrong with awk?

Comment: Your code seems to work. Are you sure file1.csv does not have trailing whitespaces for example?

Comment: are you sure the files are `.csv` or `.txt`? you say the filenames are `.csv` but in your `awk` statement you use `.txt`

Answer (score 0):

A varient in python using `csv` module:

```
import csv

with open("file1.csv") as if1:
    removals = {_id for _, _id in csv.reader(if1)}

with open("file2.csv") as if2:
    data = csv.reader(if2)
    
    with open("file2.csv", 'w') as of2:
        writer = csv.writer(of2).writerows(row for row in data if row[1] not in removals)
```

Answer (score 0):

This awk works:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{seen[$2]; next} !($2 in seen)' f1 f2
```

Prints:

```
1967-05-08,583-50-3833,Trac,Mich,Ewell,3000,Cumming,3830 Man Rid Driv,tracey@gmail.com,(111) 123-4567,0123,GA,339061
1973-11-16,183-54-5013,Carl,,Thom,30093,Norcross,1021 Ri Rid Drive,,,,,339059
```

Your awk *seems* to work as well. Are you sure that it is simple csv with no spaces in the delimiter?